# Moq, how verifing method from interface inside another interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have 2 interfaces
Interface A has one method

```
InterfaceB CreateObjectOfInterfaceB();
```

And Interface B has method

```
void DoSth();
```

How can i verify if method CreateObjectOfInterfaceB().DoSth() was used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two objects, so you'll need two mocks. Setup your first mock to return the second one, and it should be straightforward from there.

```
var mockA = new Mock<InterfaceA>();
var mockB = new Mock<InterfaceB>();

mockA.Setup(i => i.CreateObjectOfInterfaceB()).Returns(mockB.Object);

// Do your test

mockA.Verify(i => i.CreateObjectOfInterfaceB(), Times.Once);
mockB.Verify(i => i.DoSth(), Times.Once);
```